# Rails/Devise - forcing password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've implemented the ability to auto generate user passwords using Devise.  Now when the user logs in to the system, I would like to force the user to reset the password.  It seems like there is no such functionality built into Devise (please correct me if I am wrong).  I can think of several ways to achieve this, but I'm sure there is a standard way of doing this.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: it means you want to redirect user after login to change password?

Answer (score 0):

Devise handles a password controller with associated views to change a user password. In application controller you can override some devise methods like after_sign_up_path , after_sign_in_path, after_confirmation_path etc with new_password_route which I remember is the router helper to change de password, not sure though. I will think that you are sending a mail with the generated password and a confirmation link. If not, what you are doing is kind of pointless. Generating a password so then the user has to change it is not right regarding UX. Just prompt the user with the desire pass at the beginning.

Good luck